# NFS mount still connected even after box is disconnected from network

Tags: solaris, rhel5, nfs

I have a mount between a RHEL 5.6 and a Solaris 6 box acting as the NFS server.  My mount options are simply `rw,intr`.  When I disconnect the RHEL linux box from the network I am still able to write files, etc. on to my Solaris box.  After disconnecting, I map the network and of course nothing shows up, but when I re-connect and remap, everything shows up as it should.

The new files I wrote to the NFS mount on the Solaris box when I was disconnected are still there with their contents.

Is there a troll in my system or do I not understand NFS?

Comment: So RHEL is the client and solaris is the server? Once you disconnect RHEL from the network, on which system are you running the commands that write files- the RHEL system or the Sslaris one?

Comment: What does "map the network" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly.. the Solaris 6 box is the server, containing the actual filesystem that is being exported via NFS.  If that's correct, what would lead you to believe that disconnecting the client would make the files disappear on the server?

They're stored on the Solaris system... Underneath NFS it's a plain-ole file system that would behave like any other.

Comment: Everything you have said is correct.  The thing I don't get is, when I disconnect the Linux box from the network, why I am then able to `cd` to the mount point and `vi` a new file, i.e the Solaris box?

Comment: I suspect the client (RHEL) has already unmounted the filesystem internally due to a timeout.  You can verify this by doing an 'ls' inside that mount point and see if it returns (without files from the Solaris side).  If that has occured, you're simply editing a file on the local filesystem.  A mountpoint is just a directory.  The expected behavior would be that those files are no longer visible once the NFS mount is reestablished.  It works the same way with local mounts.  Now.. if you're editing on RHEL while disconnected and they show up on Solaris after, I have no explanation of that.

Comment: You led me to the culprit.  RHEL had unmounted the file system and the filesystem structure was somewhat duplicated by the previous admin on the Linux box.  What I mean is...the mount point was, for example, `/mnt/tonto` on the Solaris server this mounted to a directory containing subdirectories `sslog` and `log` on the RHEL box the subdirectories `sslog` and `log` were also created. So while I was unmounted I was looking at the RHEL `/mnt/tonto/sslog` directory.